# SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it XX.XXX.XX.XXX:443

Tags: asp.net, wcf, sockets, endpoint

I got 2 servers with two equal `wcf` services hosted on them and one client application server. I can connect to endpoints and send a requests to both services using test `wcf client app (.NET Web Service Studio)` from my local machine successfully. But when I am trying to connect from client application server using the same test `wcf client app` I successfully connected only to the one wcf service server, but I have got an error when connecting to another one:

> System.Net.WebException: There was an error downloading 'https://XXX/XXX?wsdl'. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it XX.XXX.XX.XXX:443

I performed `netstat -an | find "443"` command in command prompt on the client server and on my local machine to find out the difference and here what I have got:

**1. On my local machine:**

[image: netstat]

**2. On the client app server:**

[image]

**What I already tried to do on client application server is:**
- turned off firewall;
- stopped windows firewall service
- uninstalled mcafee virusscan enterprise application. 
(I tried to set `"prevent mass mailing worms from send mail"` first, but mcafee was in foreign language that I don't understand, so I just uninstalled it)

**after running command netstat -aon | findstr "443" on client application server I have** got this result:
[image]

but I still got an error.
Does anybody know how to solve this issue?
Could be the problem on the wcf service server side?

Comment: Run with aon instead of an. Then check if it is a wrong process hooking to port 443 instead of the desired.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I performed that with -aon. And I updated my question with this result. Another column with numbers appears. Is it processes id ? But seems like none applications using port 443. I opened a task manager and found out that 2516 pid belongs to DNS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was predictable simple one - firewall was blocking the port,
but it's important to notice that the issue was caused by firewall on the wcf service server side, but not on client application server, which is making the request to that service.
I asked the technical support of that server, and they made firewall changes.
After that error was disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and tried different ways to fix this. Nothing works. Later i found the issue which is, the application i tried to run is https and in my IIS, https binding was not created. I created binding https with the website and it works.